# Graph with strings - Edges must be numeric or character

Tags: r, igraph

Below is some code used to generate a graph displaying a generated hierarchy, but it does not show and returns the following error:

> Error in graph(devices) : 'edges' must be numeric or character

Here is the code:

```
library(igraph)

# n = num of field devices
generate_hierarchy <- function(n=100, levels=3) {
  k <- c()
  for(i in 0:n) {
    curDevice <- paste("device", i)
    # For lower levels, generate 1-2 parent units
    for(j in 0:levels) {
      p = sample(1:2, 1)
      for(k in 0:p) {
        k <- c(k, c(curDevice, paste("unit", k, j)))
      }
    }
  }
  return(devices)
}



### Generate ###

field_devices <- 100
levels <- 2*log10(field_devices)

devices <- generate_hierarchy(field_devices, levels)
print(devices)

# Creeate basic graph
g <- graph(devices)
plot(g, vertex.color = "lightcoral", vertex.size = 40, edge.color='indianred4')
```

I have seen others make a graph as follows, so I'm not sure why this code is throwing an error:

```
g <- graph(c("Person1", "Person2", "Person1", "Person3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error from running your example is

```
Error in generate_hierarchy(field_devices, levels) : 
  object 'devices' not found
```

If you change the return statement to `return (k)` then I am able to run the code without error, and can see the plot:

```
generate_hierarchy <- function(n=100, levels=3) {
  k <- c()
  for(i in 0:n) {
    curDevice <- paste("device", i)
    # For lower levels, generate 1-2 parent units
    for(j in 0:levels) {
      p = sample(1:2, 1)
      for(k in 0:p) {
        k <- c(k, c(curDevice, paste("unit", k, j)))
      }
    }
  }
  return(k)
}

field_devices <- 100
levels <- 2*log10(field_devices)

devices <- generate_hierarchy(field_devices, levels)
[enter image description here][1]
g <- graph(devices)
plot(g, vertex.color = "lightcoral", vertex.size = 40, edge.color='indianred4')
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5pD2.png (I can't embed the image due to young account age).

Comment: Thanks for that! I don't know how I didnt notice :) Is there also a way to make this a tree structure? I renamed `k` to devices as `k` was used in the for loop. So the addition of links becomes `devices <- c(devices, curDevice) devices <- c(devices, paste("unit", k, j))`